# Set division height up to desktop screen?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the height of middle division up to screen height.

If screen height is too much then it would automatically set up to screen size.

I'm talking about Coming soon (I'll update it soon!) division.

[image]

Source code is available is here

https://raharongit.github.io/posts.html

Comment: you want to set coming soon's div height as screen height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `div` with class name `post` height relative to `viewport height`.

```
.post{
height : 100vh;
}
```